# How could I live in Malaysia and work in Singapore?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, singapore, malaysia

I hold a Singapore Employment Pass and my office is in Singapore. I want to live in Johor Bahru, Malaysia. What visa, if any, would I need to rent a condo and reside in Johor Bahru? I would travel to Singapore daily. I also want to rent a car in Johor Bahru; is this possible?

Comment: What is your nationality/citizenship?

Comment: That's a Really Bad Idea™. The commute would be really tiring. Especially if you consider driving.

Comment: You should look into the charges of driving your malaysian car into Singapore, according to [LTA](https://www.lta.gov.sg/content/ltaweb/en/roads-and-motoring/driving-in-and-out-of-singapore/vehicle-entry-permit-vep-fees-toll-charge-and-reciprocal-road-charge.html) it can be almost 50$ a day.